# Is the Java API deprecated in Neo4j 1.3?

Tags: java, jruby, neo4j

It seems that for the latest 1.3 release of Neo4j only the JRuby interface is supported. Where is the Java interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java API docs http://api.neo4j.org/current/

Java REST interface, http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Using_the_Neo4j_Server_with_Java

it has a JRuby wrapper http://neo4j.org/community/languages/